# Reading oncoming information from charger in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a battery pack sitting in a charger which I have attached an FTDI cable to. When I use applications like Tera Term and connect to the serial port, information like voltage and temperature get sent from the charger to the Tera Term screen. I am trying to write a python code to do the same thing but having trouble figuring out how to get multiple lines of code from the charger to print to the screen

I have tried using ser.read()/ser.readlines() in multiple locations but nothing has worked, it runs but then I'm left in an infinite loop on the python Shell and no data gets printed

```
import serial
import os

ser = serial.Serial('COM10')
ser.baudrate = 4800
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.stopbites = 1
ser.timeout = 1

out = ser.readlines()
while ser.inWaiting():
    print(out)
```

****EDIT****
I have revised my code after some more research, the code now runs but after the first set of data is printed, I have to hit 'Enter' until the charger sends more code. How do I get it to just stay running? Also, I can't get the b''\r\n to go away in the output.

```
import serial
import os
import string

ser = serial.Serial('COM10')
ser.baudrate = 4800
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.stopbites = 1
ser.timeout = 1

while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    if not line.strip():
        out = input()
        ser.write(b'out\r\n')
    else:
        print(line)
```

OUTPUT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttzkH.png

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: @Salio Python 3.9

Comment: `b'out\r\n'` this isn't a string. It's the representation of a python bytes object. If it were the string then it would look like `"b'out\\r\\n'"`

Comment: @Salio if I don'y have that in the code, I get back an error telling me to encode to bytes